# tradingview library allow symbol change: false not working

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

Trading view widget is working fine except one parameter `allow_symbol_change: false,`. I tried this and its not working at all.

Code: -

```
const widgetOptions: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions = {
  symbol: this.props.symbol as string,
  allow_symbol_change: false,
  datafeed: Datafeed,
  interval: this.props.interval as ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions['interval'],
  container: this.props.container as ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions['container'],
  library_path: this.props.libraryPath as string,
  locale: getLanguageFromURL() || 'en',
  disabled_features: ['use_localstorage_for_settings'],
  enabled_features: ['study_templates'],
  charts_storage_url: this.props.chartsStorageUrl,
  charts_storage_api_version: this.props.chartsStorageApiVersion,
  client_id: this.props.clientId,
  user_id: this.props.userId,
  fullscreen: this.props.fullscreen,
  autosize: this.props.autosize,
  theme: 'Dark',
  studies_overrides: this.props.studiesOverrides,
  timeframe: '1w',
}
```

Is ther any other method for this also like `disable_feature`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
disabled_features: ['use_localstorage_for_settings', 'header_symbol_search']
```